# Computing using groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas, math, group-by

I have a sample dataframe `df` as shown below and I am using  `groupby` in python to solve where four columns `col` `alpha` `lambda` `n_fold` are equal then take sum of the `count` columns and perform mathematical operation like `(score*count)/sum(count)`

df =

```
    col   fold  alpha   lambda  score        n_fold count
0   0.5      0    0        1    -0.424915241    1   3966
1   0.5      1    0        1    -1.669508557    1   10182
2   0.5      2    0        1    -0.157958626    1   17048
3   0.75     0    0        1    -0.459086614    1   3966
4   0.75     1    0        1    -1.830245577    1   10182
5   0.75     2    0        1    -0.173278918    1   17048
6   1        0    0        1    -0.442985033    2   3966
7   1        1    0        1    -1.886578419    2   10182
8   1        2    0        1    -0.18286539     2   17048
```

ouput:

`col    alpha   lambda  fold         final
0   0.5       0       1      1     -0.685249027
1   0.75      0       1      1     -0.750428163
2   1         0       1      2     -0.772006323`

I have tried below code but I am not able to solve. Is there anyway to solve this.

Code: `df2 = (df.groupby(['sample', 'alpha', 'lambda', 'n_fold']).apply(lambda x: (x.score*x.count)/sum(count)).to_frame('final'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(['col', 'alpha', 'lambda', 'n_fold']).apply(lambda x: sum((x['score']*x['count']))/sum(x['count']))
Out[352]: 
col   alpha  lambda  n_fold
0.50  0      1       1        -0.685249
0.75  0      1       1        -0.750428
1.00  0      1       2        -0.772006
dtype: float64
```